# Ошибка транспонирования матрицы (замена столбцов на строки)

Tags: python, python-3.x, матрицы, линейная-алгебра

Пытаюсь транспонировать массив. То есть, чтобы столбцы стали строками.

Написал вот такое вот:

```
arr = ([[2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 4, 0],
        [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5],
        [6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0],
        [7, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
        [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 9],
        [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 22],
        [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 23]])  

x = 0
a = []
b = []
while x < 10:
    for y in range(10):
        b.append(arr[y][x])
        print(b, 'апендим к Б')
    a.append(b)
    print(a, 'апендим к А')
    x += 1
    b.clear()
    print(b, 'Очищаем Б')
print(a, 'Конец')
```

Пытаюсь найти ошибку при помощи `print`. И вот на моменте `a.append(b)` начинается ерунда. Почему-то добавляется один и тот же список в количестве равном `x` цикла `while`.
Никак не могу понять, в чём дело.

Comment: Строго говоря, транспонирование и поворот массива на бок - это разные вещи.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ошибка тут:

```
b.clear()
```

Делайте каждый раз новый список внутри цикла, так же, как вы это делаете до цикла:

```
b = []
```

Иначе у вас во всех ячейках списка `a` будет ссылка на один и тот же экземпляр списка `b`.

Answer (score 5):

Идиоматический вариант транспонирования матрицы на "Vanilla Python":

```
arr_transposed = list(zip(*arr))
```

---

результат:

```
In [15]: arr_transposed
Out[15]:
[(2, 0, 0, 0, 6, 7, 0, 0, 1, 0),
 (0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0, 1, 0),
 (0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0),
 (0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1),
 (0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1),
 (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0),
 (1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0),
 (1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
 (1, 0, 4, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0),
 (1, 3, 0, 5, 0, 0, 1, 9, 22, 23)]
```

---

**UPD:** если важно получить именно список списков, а не список кортежей, то можно сделать так, как [посоветовал @dIm0n в комментарии](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1168286/%d0%9e%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%be%d1%80%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%b1%d0%be%d0%ba/1168302?noredirect=1#comment2028654_1168302)):

```
In [25]: list(map(list, zip(*arr)))
Out[25]:
[[2, 0, 0, 0, 6, 7, 0, 0, 1, 0],
 [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0, 1, 0],
 [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0],
 [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1],
 [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0],
 [1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
 [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [1, 0, 4, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
 [1, 3, 0, 5, 0, 0, 1, 9, 22, 23]]
```

Comment: Чтобы получить тот же тип на выходе, можно использовать `list(map(list, zip(*arr)))`

Answer (score 4):

Можно сделать проще с помощью `numpy`:

```
import numpy as np

arr = ([[2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 4, 0],
        [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5],
        [6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0],
        [7, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
        [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 9],
        [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 22],
        [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 23]])

a = np.array(arr)

print(a)
print(a.T)
```